# Rewriting function to generate Java Hmac SHA512 in Node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, hmac

I have the following code in java for encrypting the plain text with key:

```
public static String calculateHMAC(String signatureKey, String textToHash) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    // Convert Hex string to byte array
    byte[] signatureKeyInByteArray = hexStringToByteArray(signatureKey);

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(signatureKeyInByteArray, "HmacSHA512");
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA512");
    mac.init(secretKeySpec);

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(mac.doFinal(textToHash.getBytes()));
}
```

In node, what i am doing:

```
function getHmacKey(data) {
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', secretKey);
hash.update(data, 'utf8');
return hash.digest('base64'); }
```

But getting different results, can't figure out what's wrong.

With string signatureKEy = "keyy" ,
textToHash = "text" ,
Outputs:

Java:
`TKVB2boNHHwkvDtmjRw2p8DNe0XWsBvodWJZAmKK5ey2Xk0+u+q3imug25Dsai32SGy5bnIr+owkWPgby7csoQ==`

Node:
`IMbZJ6hcShYMLuNi9BYWY9PB3w8/d7tOneN+ZzeSPSozgVDQYrm1x6wbKIdZIomI7lhfU4/Y10yzZgxDfmTsFA==`

Comment: In the NodeJS code the counterpart to `hexStringToByteArray()` is missing (`Buffer.from(<hex key>, 'hex')`). By the way, your example `keyy` is not compatible with hex encoding, hex digits are `0-9,a-f`.

Comment: The problem was with the key , which was shared with us :( .
Thanks a lot @topaco